# easiest way to Simplify $\frac{w^{13}+w^{12}+w^{11}}{10}$ if $w= \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

w= $\frac 1 2  (-1+i\sqrt{3})$

$( w^{13}+w^{12}+w^{11}$) 1/10

this the one of the practice question !!! is there any  easy /quick/IQ kind of way to 
simplify this ..

What I have done is :

taking $w^{11}$ common

$w^{11}( w^{2}+w^{}+1)$ 1/10

now what next ?? should substitute value of **w** ... but isn't it the long way to solve ???

Comment: Try computing $w^3$. Things should get easier from there.

Comment: Try computing $w^2+w+1$. Things should get even easier from there.

Comment: If you know about complex numbers, note that $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then you can compute the powers easily and sum them.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have tried this by addin w and subtacting so $(w+1)^{2}-w$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $\omega$ is complex cube root of unity
$$x^3-1=0$$
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$

since $\omega$ is complex cube root of unity, $\omega\neq1$

So, $\omega$  is root of $x^2+x+1=0\implies \omega^{2}+\omega+1=0$
$$\frac{\omega^{13}+\omega^{12}+\omega^{11}}{10}=\frac{\omega^{11}(\omega^{2}+\omega+1)}{10}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\cos(2\pi/3)=-1/2$ and $\sin(2\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$.

Hence 
$$\begin{align}w&=\frac{-1+ i\sqrt3}2=\cos\frac{2\pi}3+i\sin\frac{2\pi}3=e^{i2\pi/3}\\
w^3&=e^{i2\pi}=1\\
w^{12}&=(w^3)^4=1\\
\frac{w^{13}+w^{12}+w^{11}}{10}&=\frac{w^{12}(w+1+w^{-1})}{10}\\
&=\frac{1(\color{red}{e^{i2\pi/3}}+1+\color{red}{e^{-i2\pi/3}})}{10}\\
&=\frac{1(\color{red}{-1}+1)}{10}\\
&=0\\\qquad \blacksquare \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

From $w = (-1 + i\sqrt{3})/2$, we have
$$\begin{align}
(2w + 1)^{2} &= (i\sqrt{3})^{2}\\
w^{2} + w + 1 &= 0.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general it might be an idea to break high powers into powers of powers, e.g.:
$$w^{11}=(w^3)^3\cdot w^2.$$
Another good idea, especially in this case, is to use the exponential (or trig) form for $w$. In this case:
$$w=e^{2i\frac{\pi}{3}},$$
which immediately implies:
$$w^3=e^{i\cdot2\pi}=1,$$
which means you can read exponents of $w$ modulo 3 and:
$$w^{11}=w^2=e^{i\cdot\frac{4}{3}\pi}=e^{-i\cdot\frac{2}{3}\pi}=-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}{2},$$
which if looked at well enough will give you $w^2+w+1=0$ btw.

I know many other answers use more ore less the same results, but I wanted to give some general advice for similar problems.

Comment: I agree using trigonometry in this case will shorten the steps of solution but these typical things is hard to remember at time of Aptitude exam that's why I accept the answer which carries the "classical factorization" . Factorization is building block of  Mathematics !! and what I have learned that if there is any complex thing occur in maths its better to simplify it  !! and best thing is use factorization :) :) thanks every one for responding !! I highly appreciate each of you :) :)